# xsl 3.0: How to process certain child elements first in xsl:apply-templates, then the remainder (overriding document order)

Tags: xslt

Assume my xml input is a MFMATR element with a few child elements, such as: TRLIST, INTRO, and SBLIST -- in that document order.  I am converting to HTML.

I have a template that matches on the MFMATR element, and wants to run `xsl:apply-templates` on the 3 child elements, but I want INTRO to be processed first (listed first in the HTML).  The other two (TRLIST and SBLIST) should keep their relative document order, as long as INTRO comes before both of them.

So I'd like to run `<xsl:apply-templates select="INTRO, *">` but not have INTRO matched twice. (Using this syntax with xsl 3.0 causes dupes for me.)  I also don't want to explicitly list every tag in the select expression, so unknown tags will still be processed.

A 2nd real life example is this: `<xsl:apply-templates select="TITLE, CHGDESC, *"/>`.  Again, right now that is causing dupes I don't want.

I am using Saxon.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This seems to work.  If someone has a better answer, let me know and I will change it.

There is no DRY violation here -- no repeated element names or variable names.  I want it to look clean at all the call sites I will have.

It seems idiomatic to me since the function was pulled **from w3's own  website!**

```
<xsl:template match="MFMATR">
  <!-- Process INTRO first, no matter where it appears -->
  <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="INTRO, *"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="kp:distinct_nodes_stable($nodes)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="INTRO">
  <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="TITLE, CHGDESC, *"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="kp:distinct_nodes_stable($nodes)"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Discard duplicate elements in $seq, but keep their ordering -->
<!-- Adapted from https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-distinct-nodes-stable -->
<xsl:function name="kp:distinct_nodes_stable" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="seq" as="node()*"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="fold-left($seq, (),
    function($foundSoFar as node()*, $this as node()) as node()* {
      if ($foundSoFar intersect $this)
      then $foundSoFar
      else ($foundSoFar, $this)
    }) "/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: If the aim is "wants to run xsl:apply-templates on the 3 child elements, but I want INTRO to be processed first (listed first in the HTML). The other two (TRLIST and SBLIST) should keep their relative document order", how does listing an order for `TRLIST` and `SBLIST` with e.g. `SBLIST, TRLIST` ensure the relative document order is kept? And if you know the three child elements why doesn't `INTRO, TRLIST | SBLIST` not suffice to implement the requirement?

Comment: Just because a function appears (as an illustration) in the specification doesn't mean it's a good solution for the current problem. It is not. The solution using `except` appends all nodes except those that have been already processed. Your solution achieves the same thing with much more code - and also less efficiently because it has to test the explicitly named nodes twice.

Comment: I updated the answer to address Martin's comment.  We are happily using this answer today on aerospace manuals where accuracy and DRY are paramount.  If you want to use a different answer, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

> So I'd like to run `<xsl:apply-templates select="INTRO, *">` but not have INTRO matched twice

Try:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="INTRO, * except INTRO">
```

Comment: Not DRY https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I don't think this violates the DRY principle. If you had multiple elements to put first, you might define them in a variable, then do `<xsl:apply-templates select="$var, * except $var">`. But dividing a set into `x` and `not(x)` is perfectly legitimate in my view.

Comment: @KP99, I think the suggested answer is fine and the sought way for your requirement. If you are really concerned about that DRY principle then in XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 you can of course also use `select="let $intro := INTRO return ($intro, * except $intro)"` but I don't see how that would improve things, in the end for your select you want to construct the sequence of the `INTRO` followed by any child elements but the INTRO one(s) and the posted answer is the XSLT2/3 idiomatic way to express that.